# How to check if unordered lists have exactly the same elements without using python methods. (need to use loops). In python

Tags: python-2.7

list1 = ['a','b','c','d']
list2 = ['b','c','d','a']
I have these two unordered lists and want to check if both have EXACTLY the same elements. Don't want to use set() or sorted() methods. But use looping to loop through both lists.

Comment: `for item in list 1: if item in list2: #do stuff`

Comment: Without using extra storage either? Why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Keep it simple, without any helper function or list comprehension:

```
list1 = ['a','b','c','d'] 
list2 = ['b','c','d','a']

def same_lists(li1, li2):
    if len(li1) != len(li2):    # if the length of the lists is different than they are not equal so return false
        return False
    else:
        for item1 in li1:
            if item1 not in li2:
                return False    # if there is one item in li1 that is not in li2 than the lists are not identical so return false
        for item2 in li2:
            if item2 not in li1:
                return False    # same as three rows up
        return True             # if we didn't returned false for the whole list, than the lists are identical and we can return true.


print (same_lists(list1,list2))
```

Comment: You'd need to run the for loop over the 2nd list as well, otherwise the second list may have thing not in the first list (if the first list has enough repates to make them the same length). Try `list3 = ['b','c','d','a', 'a']` and `list4 = ['b','c','d','a', 'z']`

Comment: @doctorlove , That's true ! Thanks for noticing. fixed.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
common_elements = [x for x in list1 if x in list2]

if len(list1) == len(list2) == len(common_elements):
    print("EXACT SAME ELEMENTS")
else:
    print("DIFFERENT ELEMENTS")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you sort the elements first, or keep track as you encounter them, e.g. in another container, you can hand roll some solutions.

If you insist on avoiding this you need to check everything in the first list is in the seocnd and vice versa.

```
def same_lists(li1, li2):
    if len(li1) != len(li2):    
        return False
    else:
        for item in li1:
            if item not in li2:
                return False    
        for item in li2:
            if item not in li1:
                return False    
        return True
```

This returns True for `list1 = ['a','b','c','d']` compared with `list2 = ['b','c','d','a']` and `False` for `list3 = ['b','c','d','a', 'a']` and `list4 = ['b','c','d','a', 'z']`.

This is quadratic - we've compared everything with everything else (with a small optimisation checking the lengths first). We have to go through BOTH lists comaparing with the other list.

It would be quicker to sort first.